# Order JS array of strings by a query

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings and I need to order it, BUT! I have a user query. The query is a string, for example 'orange'. And I need to order it to show the values similar to 'orange' at the top of the list.

For now, I achieved a function that can order it by the first character of the query.

```
function comparisonFnction(a, b) {
    const aeq = a[0].toLowerCase() == query.charAt(0).toLowerCase()
    const beq = b[0].toLowerCase() == query.charAt(0).toLowerCase()

    if aeq == beq
        return 0
    elif aeq
        return -1
    else
        return 1
}
strings_array = strings_array.sort(comparisonFnction)
```

But I want to order it by all the characters of the query, in order to show to the user the most relevant search results.

Thanks!

Comment: that's a pretty complex algorithm, it's unlikely that you'll see an answer posted in this site's format.  might want to look at a tool designed for this kind of thing, like underscore or lodash

Comment: You'd have to come up with a suitable score/relevance function – to start with, you could look at how many characters the user's query has in common with your string.

Comment: @Claies It's not that complex and doesn't really require Lodash :) See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example of a score heuristic function (it looks at characters in order in both strings).

```js
const fruits = "Apples Avocados Bananas Blackberries Blueberries Cantaloupe Cherries Grapes Lemons Limes Mangoes Nectarines Oranges Peaches Pears Pineapple Plums Raspberries Strawberries Watermelon".split(
  " ",
);

// Clean a string for comparison.
// Lower-cases the value, then removes everything but alphanumerics.
function cleanString(s) {
  return s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z]+/g, "");
}

// Compute a search relevance score for an item.
function scoreSearch(search, item) {
  item = cleanString(item);
  search = cleanString(search);
  let score = 0;
  let p = 0; // Position within the `item`
  // Look through each character of the search string, stopping at the end(s)...
  for (var i = 0; i < search.length && p < item.length - 1; i++) {
    // Figure out if the current letter is found in the rest of the `item`.
    const index = item.indexOf(search[i], p);
    // If not, stop here.
    if (index < 0) {
      break;
    }
    // If it is, add to the score...
    score++;
    // ... and skip the position within `item` forward.
    p = index;
  }
  return score;
}

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  // Get user input...
  const input = e.target.value;

  // Map each item with a score resulting in `[["apple", 3], ["banana", 2]]`)
  const itemScores = fruits.map((f) => [f, scoreSearch(input, f)]);
  // Remove non-matches
  const filteredItemScores = itemScores.filter(([text, score]) => score > 0);
  // Sort the pairs descending by the score
  filteredItemScores.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  // Format text for output:
  const output = filteredItemScores
    .map(([text, score]) => `${text} (${score})`)
    .join("\n");
  // Show output
  document.getElementById("output").value = output || "No fruit found!";
});
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input" placeholder="search for fruit!"><br/>
<textarea id="output" cols="30" rows="15" readonly></textarea>
```